# html5 video with 100% works with no DOCTYPE (videojs)

Tags: css, html, html5-video, video.js

The following HTML doesn't result in video-size of 100%. If I remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` everything works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="video-js/video.js"></script>
    <script>videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js/video-js.swf"</script>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="myVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin video-container" width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay preload="auto" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup="{}">
      <source src="test.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

It's recomended to define a DOCTYPE for every HTML page. I could leave it but then it won't work with IE Version < 10.

I've searched about that problem and found [this solutions](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1868-width-and-height-to-100) but they don't work with my DOCTYPE.

Do I miss here something basic?

I'm using videojs 4.0.3.

EDIT: according to tips and an answer for this question I provide here a solution:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video id="myVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload="auto" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup="{}">
      <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
    </video>
</div>
```

and the corresponding css:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video-js {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont' know the exact details as to why this is, but with I'm seeing that with doctype html (the correct HTML5 doctype) the width/height of the html page is not 100% by default. If you add the following somewhere in your css, that should fix your issue.

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/uyelud/1/edit

Comment: I had some success defining it with CSS and !important markers but since I'm using it within twitter bootstrap, it seems to be tricky to make it there 100%.

Comment: I can't speak to how bootstrap might be affecting all of this, but whatever video.js is inside of needs to have a width and height itself.

Comment: I will provide a possible solution in my question above about all this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal, I just edited the `videojs.tpl.php` file and took out the

```
width="<?php print $width; ?>"
```

and added `width="100%"`